# prove that $x^2 + 5 =y^3$ has no solutions for $x,\ y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

So the question is completely stated by the title. My own thoughts:

I can prove that $x^2 + 1 = y^3$ has no solutions for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ by using the factorization:
$$ y^3 = (x-i)(x+i) $$
in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD and that $(x-i)$ and $(x+i)$ are coprime we obtain that they are both cubes and it follows that this is impossible.

Now I would like to apply similar reasoning for this equation, we factor it as follows:
$$ y^3 = (x-\sqrt{-5})(x+\sqrt{-5}) $$
in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ but this time $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD. However, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite seperable field extension we find that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is a Dedekind domain, this integral closure is exactly our ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ (which follows from the fact that $-5 = 3 \neq 1 \text{ mod } 4$). In a Dedekind domain we know that we write ideals uniquely as a product of maximal ideals, we can apply this to the ideal $(y)$, $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ for this to be useful we must first prove that the ideals $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ are coprime, for this it suffices to show that there is no prime ideal $P \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ that contains $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x+\sqrt{-5})$.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal s.t. $x-\sqrt{-5},x+\sqrt{-5} \in P$, then it follows that also:
$$ 2\sqrt{-5} = x+\sqrt{-5} - (x-\sqrt{-5}) \in P $$
and thus by the given equality:
$$ -20 = (2\sqrt{-5})^2 \in P^2 \subseteq (y)^3 $$
so we find an element $a+b \sqrt{-5} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ s.t. $-20 = (a+b\sqrt{-5}) \cdot y^3$ using the norm:
$$ N(r + s \sqrt{-5}) := r^2 +s^2 5 $$
we obtain from this equality thath:
$$ 400 = (a^2 + 5b^2) \cdot y^6 $$
but as $400 = 2^4 \cdot 5^2$ we find that $y$ must be equal to $1$ and thus we find that:
$$ x^2 + 5 = 1 $$
which is clearly impossible as for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $x^2 \geq 0$.

From this we can conclude that $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ are indeed coprime so their decomposition in a product of maximal ideals is disjoint (i.e. we find maximal ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{p}_r$, $\mathfrak{q}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{q}_s$ and natural numbers $e_1,\dots,e_r,f_1,\dots,f_s$ s.t.: 
$$(x-\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\dots\mathfrak{p}_r^{e_r}, \qquad (x+\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{q}_1^{f_1}\dots\mathfrak{q}_r^{f_r}$$
where all $\mathfrak{p}_i$ and $\mathfrak{q}_j$ are different. For $(y)$ we also find such a decomposition, which implies that the decompositions of $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ must be of the form:
$$ (x-\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{p}_1^{3e_1}\dots\mathfrak{p}_r^{3e_r}, \qquad (x+\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{q}_1^{3f_1}\dots\mathfrak{q}_r^{3f_r} $$
which implies that there is some ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ s.t. $(x+\sqrt{-5}) = I^3$ so we find elements of $I$: $a_i+ b_i \sqrt{-5} \in I$ for which:
$$ x+\sqrt{-5} = \prod_{i=1}^3(a_i+ b_i \sqrt{-5}) $$
and then I would like that this is impossible, but at this point I'm stuck.

I'm sorry if my own idea is absolutaly worthless but this is the first time I try to solve this kind of exercise.

Comment: Mordell's equation $y^2=x^3-n$ has no solution for $n=3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 21, 22, \ldots $. See [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&ei=zxQxVc77ItLbavC6gPgC&usg=AFQjCNExJsQ8bikneg2KeVVzvOH_vwlctQ&bvm=bv.91071109,d.d2s).

Comment: Sweet, thanks the proof is significantly simpler than what I had in mind :)

Comment: 1) $y=2l\Rightarrow x^2+5=8l^3\equiv 0\equiv 1+5\pmod{8}$, contr.
 2) $y$ odd $\Rightarrow x=2k\Rightarrow 4(k^2+1)=(y-1)(y^2+y+1)\Rightarrow y\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, but $y^2+y+1\equiv 1+1+1\equiv 3\pmod {4}$, impossible, since $\exists p\in\mathbb P (p=4c+3\mid k^2+1)$.

Comment: When you say $y = 1$ from $y^6 = 1$, actually you can only say $y = \pm 1$.  But you still get a contradiction after that, as before.

Comment: You are absolutaly right!

Comment: Do you know about ideal class groups?  The ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ has class number $2$, which is relatively prime to the exponent $3$ in the equation, so *even though* $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD one can prove that $x+\sqrt{-5}$ must be a cube in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, which is the kind of conclusion you'd expect if $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ were a UFD. Trying to solve $x + \sqrt{-5} = (a + b\sqrt{-5})^3$ in integers $a$ and $b$ leads to a contradiction by looking at the coefficient of $\sqrt{-5}$ on both sides. That's how you solve this with algebraic number theory.

Comment: I had heard of the ideal class group but I don't really know anything about them except their definition (I'm not at all experienced in algebraic number theory)

Comment: @Holymonk Do you understand my solution? I wanted to make the solution succinct, so I can clarify if anything's not clear. The solution checks 2 cases. Since in the first case $x$ is odd, we know $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {8}$.  In the 2nd case, since $y^2+y+1$ is odd, we know $4\mid y-1$. Then I used the fact that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ with $p$ odd prime. I used [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) here.

Comment: This question is by no means a duplicate of the proposed one, and it is a rather shame that moderators here go around closing interesting questions without a good-enough reason!!!

Comment: @user31415 I almost understand your answer, so I can follow it to the point when you say $y \equiv 1 (\text{mod }4)$, but then there are 2 things unclear:
1. is there an easy proof to see that equivalence of the Legendre symbol?
2. How can we use this to get a contradiction (I don't know the notation "$\mathbb{P}(p = 4c+3 \mid k^2 +1)"$). I'm sorry for the late response I was on a trip this weekend and thanks for the proof, I confirmed that my question was a duplicate because I found a proof using the link provided by Dietrich Burde. But I think the proof of user31415 is better!

Comment: @Holymonk I'll re-write it a bit: ..but $y^2+y+1\equiv 1+1+1\equiv 3\pmod {4}$, which means $\exists p=4c+3\in\mathbb P (p\mid k^2+1)$. But $p\mid k^2+1\Rightarrow k^2\equiv -1\pmod {p}\Rightarrow \text{ord}_p k=4\stackrel{\text{FLT}}\Rightarrow 4\mid p-1\Rightarrow p=4m+1$, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: @user3141: I'm sorry but I still don't fully understand, why can you conclude that $\textup{ord}_p(k) = 4$ and is $FLT$ Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @Holymonk \text{FLT} is Fermat's Little Theorem. Fact: If $\text{ord}_n a = s, a^k\equiv 1\pmod {n}$, then $s\mid k$. Proof: Let $k=sl+r, 0\le r<s$. Then $a^{sl+r}\equiv a^{sl}a^{r}\equiv \left(a^s\right)^la^r\equiv a^r\equiv 1\pmod {n}$. But $s$ is the least positive number such that $a^s\equiv 1\pmod {n}$, and $0\le r<s$, so $r$ can't be positive and is $0$. Then $k=sl$.$\ \ \ \square$ Since in our case $k^4\equiv 1\pmod {p}$, we know $\text{ord}_p k=1,2,4$. It's not $2$, because $k^2\equiv -1\pmod {p}$ and it's not $1$, since $k\equiv 1\pmod {p}$ would imply $k^2\equiv 1\pmod {p}$, contr.

Comment: @Holymonk More generally, $a^{q^{n}}\equiv -1\pmod {m}\Rightarrow \text{ord}_m a=q^{n+1}$ (with $q$ prime). Proof: assume $\text{ord}_m a\neq q^{n+1}$. Then $\text{ord}_m a=q^{k}, 0<q^k<q^{n+1}$. But then $(a^{q^{k}})^{q^{n-k}}\equiv 1^{q^{n-k}}\equiv 1\not\equiv -1\pmod{m}$, contradiction.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks man!

Comment: You are the number theory magician! :)

Comment: @KCd: I know what you mean now and that way is nice also :)