# Showing that $x^2+5=y^3$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, dedekind-domain

I'm trying to show that the Diophantine equation $x^2+5=y^3$ has no integer solutions using the fact that $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-5}]$ has class number two. I think I have the general idea, but I'm having a tough time establishing the statement in bold below. Any ideas?

The equation gives a factorization into ideals 
$$
(x+\sqrt{-5})(x-\sqrt{-5})=(y)^3
$$
in $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-5}]$. **Assuming that $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ are relatively prime**, we know that $(x+\sqrt{-5})=\mathfrak a^3$ and $(x-\sqrt{-5})=\mathfrak b^3$ for some ideals $\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b$ in $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-5}]$. Then the classes of $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ have order dividing 3 in the class group, hence they must both be principal, generated by some $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, respectively, as the class number is 2. Hence $\alpha^3=x+\sqrt{-5}$ up to units ($\pm 1$), and matching up real and imaginary parts then gives a contradiction.

How can I show that the ideals $(x+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(x-\sqrt{-5})$ are relatively prime? I was trying something along the lines of letting $\mathfrak p$ be a prime of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ diving both ideals, in which case it also divides their sum (gcd). Then $$2\sqrt{-5}=x+\sqrt{-5}-(x-\sqrt{-5})\in (x+\sqrt{-5},x-\sqrt{-5})\subseteq \mathfrak p,$$ so $\mathfrak p\mid (2\sqrt{-5})$... But I'm not totally sure where I'm going with this.

Comment: Just realized this could be a duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239090/prove-that-x2-5-y3-has-no-solutions-for-x-y-in-mathbbz?rq=1. Will read this solution to see if it answers my question...

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD.

Comment: Right, but it is a Dedekind domain, so we have unique factorization of ideals.

Comment: That's indeed the case.

Comment: So, I don't think my question is a duplicate: in the link above, @KCd's comment essentially explains the method outlined above, but does not shed light on how to show the ideals are relatively prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathfrak p\mid(2\sqrt{-5})$, so $\mathfrak p\mid(2)$ or $\mathfrak p\mid(\sqrt{-5})$. Since $(2),(\sqrt{-5})$ are prime, $\mathfrak p$ is equal to one of them. We can't have $\mathfrak p=(2)$, since $2\nmid x+\sqrt{-5}$, so $\mathfrak p=(\sqrt{-5})$, so $\sqrt{-5}\mid x+\sqrt{-5}$. This implies $5\mid x$, and you can derive a contradiction from $x^2+5=y^3$.

EDIT: As Yong Hao Ng notes in the comment, $(2)$ is not a prime ideal - it factors as $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$, so we get that $\mathfrak p=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. Then $x+\sqrt{-5}\in(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, so $x-1\in(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and we get $x$ is odd. Now we get a contradiction from $x^2+5\equiv 2\pmod 4$, since $y^3$ can't be even but indivisible by $4$.

Comment: @Servaes That isn't right - this is true in any ring as long as $\mathfrak p$ is prime, at least assuming we define $I\mid J$ as $J\subseteq I$. We don't need $(2),(\sqrt{-5})$ prime for this either.

Comment: (+1) but I'm wondering if $(2)$ isn't prime and $$(2)=(2,1-\sqrt 5)^2$$ instead. The ring mod $(2)$, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]/(2)$, has the residue classes $\{0,1,\sqrt 5,1+\sqrt 5\}$ and there is a zero divisor since $$(1+\sqrt 5)^2 = 6+2\sqrt 5 \equiv 0\pmod 2$$ But the residue ring should be an integral domain.

Comment: @YongHaoNg I'm afraid you are right (except we are in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, not $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$). I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @Wojowu  I'm afraid I don't understand your argument on the odness of $x$. As I interpret it, you write $x-1$ under the form $2a+b(1-\sqrt{-5})$, but here $a, b \in \mathbf Z[\sqrt {-5}]$, so I think you can't conclude a priori. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo If $x-1$ was odd, say of the form $2k+1$, then $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ would also contain $x-1-2k=1$. In general, if you have a proper ideal $I$ in a number ring containing a rational prime $p$, then $I\cap\mathbb Z=(p)$.

Comment: OK. I misinterpreted your argument.

Comment: Cool, this is so much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered many times on this site, so it is certainly a duplicate. On the other hand, it may be still worth to give the link to a very nice lecture note by Keith Conrad [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwib5fP-qongAhUIM-wKHW1UCa0QFjAAegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw372se8ny4lcStU6iD9MbWS), where he does proofs for many interesting cases of the Mordell equation $y^2=x^3-n$. For $n=5$ there are no integer solutions. More references here are found at [OEIS A054504](https://oeis.org/A054504).

Comment: In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107304/showing-that-gcd-does-not-exist-for-31-sqrt-5-and-31-sqrt-5-in-m) such ideals are considered in Arturo's answer, but there are still better posts, I suppose.

Comment: You were almost there.

Answer (score 2):

In the ideal factorization $(x+\sqrt {-5})(x-\sqrt {-5})=(y)^3$, "how can I show that the ideals $(x \pm \sqrt {-5})$ are relatively prime?" Suppose that $P$ is a common prime  divisor, then $P^{2a}$ will appear in the LHS of the factorization. But $P^{3b}$ will appear in the RHS because of the cube, hence at least $P^6$ will divide both sides because of uniqueness. Following your argument, $P^3$ must divide $(2)(\sqrt {-5})$. In the quadratic field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-5})$, we know that the prime $5$ is totally ramified, and $(5)=(\sqrt {-5})^2$ shows that $(\sqrt {-5})$ is prime. Besides $(2)=Q^2$, with $Q=(2, 1+\sqrt {-5})$ (so the class of $Q$ is the unique class of order $2$ of the class group). It follows again by uniqueness of factorization that $P^3$ cannot divide $(\sqrt {-5})Q^2$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

If ideals $I,J$ are relatively prime then their sum generates the ring $R$, so we can show this. In particular we can show also that
$$
(a + b\sqrt {- 5})(x+ \sqrt{- 5}) + (c + d\sqrt {- 5})(x - \sqrt {- 5}) = 1
$$
for some $a,b,c,d$.

This gives the equations
$$
\begin{align}
(a+c)x - 5(b-d) &= 1\\
(a-c) + (b+d)x &= 0
\end{align}
$$
So a necessary condition is $5$ does not divide $x$. This can be checked to be true from $x^2 + 5 = y^3$, but otherwise the ideals are not necessarily relatively prime in general.

---

Setting
$$
c = a + (b+d)x
$$
gives us
$$
2ax = (1+5(b-d)) - (b+d)x^2
$$
Taking $\pmod 2$ we see that $x$ must be even, so to get an integer solution for $a$ we must have $1+5(b-d)$ divisible by $2x$.

The obvious way is to look at the linear diophantine solutions
$$
xu - 5v = 1
$$
We can always choose $u$ to be even, so now we can set $d=0, v=b$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{1+5(b-d)}{2x} - (b+d)\frac{x}{2}\\
&= \frac{1+5v}{2x} - v\frac{x}{2}\\
&= \frac{u}{2} - v\frac{x}{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since $u/2$ is integral we just need $vx$ to be even, which is true based on an earlier assumption: $x$ must be even.

---

It remains to show that $x$ is indeed even. 
If $x=2m+1$ is odd, then $y$ is even and
$$
x^2 + 5 = 4m^2+4m+ 6 \equiv 2\pmod 4
$$
which contradicts $y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Hence $x$ is even and we are done, finding a solution to the initial equation as
$$
(u/2 -vx/2 + v\sqrt {-5})(x + \sqrt {-5}) + (u/2 + vx/2)(x - \sqrt {-5}) = 1
$$
(Recall that $xu-5v=1$ and $u$ chosen to be even.)

Since the two ideals generate $1$, they are relatively prime.